# How can I tell if emacs was built with X support?

Tags: gui-emacs, build, x-window

Is there a variable like `system-configuration-options` that will provide the *computed* features of the running emacs?  Specifically, I'm looking for X support (`--with-x=yes|no`).

Ultimately I'm trying to figure out why emacs isn't starting in GUI mode, but I recently had the bone-headed realization that I'd originally built emacs before installing any X environment.  So I re-installed X and my `./configure` call does mention X and GTK, so I would imagine that the support is there, but I'm not seeing emacs use a GUI.  `xeyes` and even `gedit` work.

From `./configure`:

```
...
checking for X... libraries , headers
...
checking for GTK... yes
checking whether GTK compiles... yes
...
```

After I ran `make clean && make && make install`, running `emacs` still opens in terminal mode :-(

If I can determine that emacs was indeed built with X support, I'll probably ask a separate question about why it's not working :-(

Comment: Is the Emacs version that is launching the one you expected, and of course, you want to avoid calling an alias that automatically uses the command-line argument `-nw`?

Comment: I am launching the right emacs version (26.1) and `which emacs` produces `/usr/local/bin/emacs` (if memory serves; I'm building again now with an explicit `--with-x11` configuration option). According to the answer below, X11 was indeed *not* one of the features available in that emacs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that if `system-configuration-features` includes `X11` then Emacs was compiled with X support.

That value is set in `configure` by the `HAVE_X11` variable being true (look for: `emacs_config_features=`), which in turn is based on `window_system=x11` which you can trace back through a more complicated set of tests.

Comment: Ack, I should've remembered that variable! X11 was *not* one of the options there -- so that explains why it wasn't working. Reconfiguring/rebuilding emacs with an explicit `--with-x11` now pops up an X window as expected. Thanks so much!